# Resize Div whilst maintaining ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm trying to create a page where a centrally placed div resizes to fit in the page both horizontally and vertically whilst retaining the ratio.

Currently I'm using a combination of JS and CSS although I'm not sure it's particularly efficient - it also seems a little hacky.

How would I either clean up this code or rewrite it to achieve this?

Javascript

```
function changesize(){

var $width = $(".aspectwrapper").height();
var $changewidth = $width * 1.5;
var $doc = $(document).width();
var $height;

if ($doc <= $changewidth){ $changewidth = ( $doc - 100 );
$height = ( ($doc - 100) / 1.5 );
$(".aspectwrapper").css('height', "" + $height + "");
};


$(".content").css('width', "" + $changewidth + "");
$(".aspectwrapper").css('width', "" + $changewidth + "");
};

$(document).ready(function(e) {

 $(changesize); 

});

$(window).resize(function(e) {

$(changesize); 

});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.aspectwrapper {
display: inline-block; 
position: relative; 
margin: 0 auto;
height: 90%;
border: #F00 1px solid;
background-color: #F00;
}
.content {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 60px;
outline: thin dashed green; 
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #09C;
}
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #0F3;
float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="aspectwrapper">
                <div class="content"> CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally position my center div horizontally and vertically using positioning/margin combinations with a specific liquid width and height. It would resize based on page width without the use of javascript. Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Aw2Y/

Comment: Whilst this does resize the div based on browser size, I need to maintain the same ratio of the size of the DIV, specifically 1:1.5 height to width - the css method does not keep this ratio.

Comment: In that case, I'd use jQuery to adjust the CSS on document load. I'd send the height of the div to a variable and change the `.css()` of the element for the width (i.e. `.css('width','x*1.5');`) as well as the length of the margin-left for the element (`.css('left','-x*.75');`).